# Damped oscilliation with forcing

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ode is defined as follows

$ x''+bx'+\omega^2 x=\cos (v \cdot t)$, where $\omega, v, b >0$

I'm asked to show, that if $b > 2 \omega $ then every solution of this equation tends
to some fixed sinusoidal function as $t \rightarrow +\infty$, and write down the formula for this limiting sinusoidal function.

What I have done so far is to consider the homogenous case

$x''+bx'+\omega^2 x=0$

Where we see that $b> 2 \omega$ means that its discriminant is posive, and its
easily seen it has complex roots with negative realpart. But im not sure on how to continue with the exercise from here on. Any help?

Comment: How about using the method of undetermined coefficients to  find a particular solution, i.e., try looking for solutions of the form $x=c_1\cos(vt)+c_2\sin(vt)$?

Comment: I tried that approach but it did not really lead anywhere. If I set $x=c_1 \cos (vt)+c_2 \sin (vt)$ I get the following: $ \cos(vt)(-v^2c_1+bvc_2+\omega^2-1)+\sin(vt) (-v^2c_2-c_1vb+c_2 \omega^2)=0$   i cant really see a way of getting this expression on a form such that i can say something about $c_1$ and $c_2$, and my assumption that $b > 2\omega$ doesn't help much either in this case.

Answer (score 1):

For the homogeneous solution, we get roots:

$$m^2 + bm + w^2 \implies m_{1, 2} = -\dfrac {b}{2}~\pm~\sqrt{b^2 - 4 w^2}$$

We can now write:

$$x_h(t) = c_1 e^{\frac{1}{2} t \left(-\sqrt{b^2-4 w^2}-b\right)}+c_2 e^{\frac{1}{2} t \left(\sqrt{b^2-4 w^2}-b\right)}$$

For the particular solution, we choose:

$$x_p(t) = r \cos(v t) + s \sin(v t)$$

We solve for the constants $s$ (the $\frac{bv}{b^2 v^2+\left(v^2-w^2\right)^2}$ expression below) and $r$ (the $\frac{w^2-v^2}{b^2 v^2+\left(v^2-w^2\right)^2}$ expression) and our final solution is:

$$x(t) = c_1 e^{\frac{1}{2} t \left(-\sqrt{b^2-4 w^2}-b\right)}+c_2 e^{\frac{1}{2} t \left(\sqrt{b^2-4 w^2}-b\right)}+\frac{b v \sin  (v t)}{b^2 v^2+\left(v^2-w^2\right)^2}+\frac{(w^2-v^2) \cos  (v t)}{b^2 v^2+\left(v^2-w^2\right)^2}$$

Can you continue? Can you convert cosine term to a sine term and then see what happens as $t \rightarrow +\infty$?

It often helps to try some values if not, so for $c_1 = c_2 = 1, b = 5, v = 3, w = 2$, we have:

$$x(t) = e^{-4 t}+e^{-t}+\frac{3}{50} \sin (3 t)-\frac{1}{50} \cos (3 t) = e^{-4 t}+e^{-t}+\frac{3}{50} \sin (3 t)-\frac{1}{50} \sin \left(3 t+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$$

What do you notice when you plot this?

Now, see if you can analytically conclude this from the general expression (exponential terms go to zero and the trig terms...).